# Calendar buttons aren't being removed correctly - Lua

Tags: mobile, calendar, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a calendar to be able to switch from month to month. My problem is in removing each day button when the next or previous buttons are touched.

Here is my code for the Previous Button to switch from the current month to the previous month. My Next button code is almost exactly the same. It works perfectly fine when I tap the button for the first time, but when I tap it again, I get an error at the child:removeSelf() line, and the print message tells me there are 61 elements in the table. It seems to add extra buttons to the table every time I go to a month that hasn't been seen yet.

This is really frustrating to me because I don't see any reason why the code is making extra buttons for every month, and even if it does, each one should still get removed when the button is tapped. Can someone please help me?

```
local prev_function = function(event)

    if event.phase == "release" then

        today.year = 2012
        today.month = 3
        today.day = 29
        today.wday = 5


        if monthNum == 1 then 
            monthNum = 12
            yearNum = yearNum - 1
        elseif monthNum ~= 1 then
            monthNum = monthNum - 1
        end

        local month = ""

            if monthNum == 1 then month = "January"
        elseif monthNum == 2 then month = "February"
        elseif monthNum == 3 then month = "March"
        elseif monthNum == 4 then month = "April"
        elseif monthNum == 5 then month = "May"
        elseif monthNum == 6 then month = "June"
        elseif monthNum == 7 then month = "July"
        elseif monthNum == 8 then month = "August"
        elseif monthNum == 9 then month = "September"
        elseif monthNum == 10 then month = "October"
        elseif monthNum == 11 then month = "November"
        elseif monthNum == 12 then month = "December"
           end

        monthText.text = month .. " " .. yearNum

        print("Table elements before button deletion: " .. #buttonTable)

        for i = #buttonTable, 1, -1 do
            --[[if button[i] ~= nil then
                table.remove(buttonTable)
                button[i]:removeSelf()
                button[i] = nil
            end--]]

            local child = table.remove(buttonTable)
            if child ~= nil then
                child:removeSelf()
                child = nil
            end
        end

        print("Table elements after button deletion: " .. #buttonTable)

        next_button.alpha = 1


        for i = 1, math.floor(numYears * 365.25) do

            dateTable[i] = calendar.getInfo(today) --calculate the next day's date

            if dateTable[i].year == yearNum and dateTable[i].month == monthNum then  -- create a button if the date's year and month match the desired month
                button[i] = ui.newButton{
                    default = "images/day.png",
                    over = "images/dayover.png",
                    text = dateTable[i].day,
                    size = 30,
                    font = native.systemFontBold,
                    textColor = {0, 0, 0, 255},
                    onEvent = addExpense_function,
                    offset = -35        }

                    if dateTable[i].wday == 1 then button[i].x = math.floor(col/2)
                elseif dateTable[i].wday == 2 then button[i].x = (col * 1) + math.floor(col/2)
                elseif dateTable[i].wday == 3 then button[i].x = (col * 2) + math.floor(col/2)
                elseif dateTable[i].wday == 4 then button[i].x = (col * 3) + math.floor(col/2)
                elseif dateTable[i].wday == 5 then button[i].x = (col * 4) + math.floor(col/2)
                elseif dateTable[i].wday == 6 then button[i].x = (col * 5) + math.floor(col/2)
                elseif dateTable[i].wday == 7 then button[i].x = (col * 6) + math.floor(col/2)
                     end

                    if dateTable[i].day == 1 then button[i].y = wDayBar.y + wDayBar.height/2 + math.floor(row/2)
                elseif dateTable[i].wday == 1 then button[i].y = button[i-1].y + row
                else button[i].y = button[i-1].y
                     end        
            end

            today = dateTable[i]
            table.insert(buttonTable, button[i])
            --button[i].id = "button_" .. i

        end
        print("Table elements after button creation: " .. #buttonTable)

    end

    return true

end
```

Comment: "`if ... then ... elseif ... then ...`" Stop doing this. You're in *Lua*; use proper Lua idioms. Create a table that is indexed by the month index, and who's values are the names of the months. In fact, almost every time you find yourself wanting a switch statement, you should be using a table, where the values are either functions to call or some data you want to convert the key into.

Comment: Assuming you mean something like this: `local monthTable = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}`
`local month = monthTable[monthNum]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the code in the question doesn't work (and putting the `table.insert` inside the `if...then` does work) is due to the way you're using the `button` table.

The loop that starts `for i = 1, math.floor(numYears * 365.25) do` is going to create indices from 1 to a few hundred/thousand (depending on `numYears`).

However, as you're using `button[i]=` for filling the table and you're only filling 30 or so at a time, what you're creating is a sparse table with a few non-nil entries somewhere in the middle of the table.

Now with `table.insert(buttonTable, button[i])` outside the `if..then` what actually happens is that most of the "inserts" are inserting `nil`. First time around this actually works ok for 2 reasons:

- inserting `nil` on an empty table does nothing nor does inserting `nil` at the end of a table
- there are only a month's worth of non-nil entries in `button` so only a month's worth will be inserted into `buttonTable`

With `button` and `buttonTable` setup like this, the first part of the call to the previous or next functions works as expected and `removeSelf` will be called on the month's worth of buttons. However this doesn't actually remove the button from the `button` table.

So when you come to the `numYears` loop again, not only will you add your freshly created buttons to both `button` and `buttonTable`, you'll also still have the buttons that you've just called `removeSelf` on in `button` so these will be added to `buttonTable` again. Crucially though, they are just tables now, so when you call `removeSelf` on them the second time it barfs. I presume this is the cause of the error you saw.

Moving `table.insert(buttonTable, button[i])` to the `if...then` will resolve this problem as it will only ever add freshly minted buttons to `buttonTable` that are then removed each time next or previous are called.

A word of caution though. The `button` table is a bit of a mess. After a bit of navigating around, it'll have a bunch of dead buttons (that can't be garbage collected unless you've declared the values as weak) plus a month of working buttons. If you were to try to do anything with it, the chances are that you'll get problems.

It's not clear from the code if you even need the `button` table. If it's not required elsewhere it would probably be safer to just hold the button references in `buttonTable`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It definitely helped a lot, and not only does it help improve my current code, but it also has enhanced my knowledge of how Lua tables work!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from making a new table for months as well as column coordinates like Nicol suggested, I found that I needed to put the table.insert() command inside the `if ... then` structure. I'm not sure exactly why putting it immediately after the `if ... then` structure caused it to not work properly, but I'm guessing it's because the buttons are being created inside the structure.

```
local prev_function = function(event)

    if event.phase == "release" then

        --set date to start from
        today.year = 2012
        today.month = 2
        today.day = 29
        today.wday = 4

        --determine new month number
        if monthNum == 1 then 
            monthNum = 12
            yearNum = yearNum - 1
        elseif monthNum ~= 1 then
            monthNum = monthNum - 1
        end

        --set month string
        local month = monthTable[monthNum]

        monthText.text = month .. " " .. yearNum

        print("Table elements before button deletion: " .. #buttonTable)

        --remove all elements in buttonTable
        for i = #buttonTable, 1, -1 do
            local child = table.remove(buttonTable)
            if child ~= nil then
                child:removeSelf()
                child = nil
            end
        end

        print("Table elements after button deletion: " .. #buttonTable)

        next_button.alpha = 1
        --hide prev_button if we get to the month after the month we started from
        if monthNum == today.month + 1 and yearNum == today.year then
            prev_button.alpha = 0
        end


        --generate dates for specified number of years
        for i = 1, math.floor(numYears * 365.25) do

            dateTable[i] = calendar.getInfo(today)

            --create a button for each date inside desired month
            if dateTable[i].year == yearNum and dateTable[i].month == monthNum then
                button[i] = ui.newButton{
                    default = "images/day.png",
                    over = "images/dayover.png",
                    text = dateTable[i].day,
                    size = 30,
                    font = native.systemFontBold,
                    textColor = {0, 0, 0, 255},
                    onEvent = addExpense_function,
                    offset = -35        }

                    --set x and y
                    button[i].x = colTable[dateTable[i].wday]

                        if dateTable[i].day == 1 then button[i].y = wDayBar.y + wDayBar.height/2 + math.floor(row/2)
                    elseif dateTable[i].wday == 1 then button[i].y = button[i-1].y + row
                    else button[i].y = button[i-1].y
                         end        


                table.insert(buttonTable, button[i])
            end

            --change 'today' for next iteration in the for loop
            today = dateTable[i]

        end
        print("Table elements after button creation: " .. #buttonTable)


    end

    return true

end
```